# Represent the $n$-qubit $2^n\times2^n$ size Hadamard/quantum Fourier transform unitary square matrix as product of $k$ two-level unitary matrices

Tags: quantum-fourier-transform, hadamard

I wish to know if it is possible to express the n-qubit Hadamard unitary square matrix of size $2^n * 2^n$ as a product of 'k' two-level unitary square matrices where 'k' is of the order of polynomial in 'n'. By order is meant the Big-O notation of computational complexity theory. By the 2-level matrix, I mean the definition in the book "Quantum Computation and quantum information" by Nielsen and Chuang,  section 4.5.1 "Two level unitary gates are universal", pp. 189. A two-level unitary matrix is a unitary matrix which acts non-trivially only on two-or-fewer vector components.

I also wish to know if the same decomposition into 'k' two-level unitary square matrices can be done to a Quantum Fourier Transform (QFT) unitary square matrix of n-qubits of size $2^n * 2^n$ where 'k' is of the order of polynomial in 'n'.

I have read that the two-level unitary gates/square matrices are universal.

Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Comment: If the unitaries belong to $U(N)$ then this can always be done; see https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.73.58 and https://doi.org/10.1364/OPTICA.3.001460 and https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevA.97.022328 for various schemes. If they do not (and thus do not conserve something like the total number of ground-state qubits) then these schemes do not apply

Comment: @QuantumMechanic if I remember correctly, Reck's and similar schemes provide decompositions of $N\times N$ unitaries in terms of $\mathcal O(N^2)$ two-level ones. OP is asking for decompositions using $\mathcal O({\rm poly}(\log N))$ two-level unitaries I think, which clearly can only be done for specific cases. You can definitely do it for the Hadamard, as that can be written as a tensor product $\bigotimes_{k=1}^n H$, where $2^n=N$, and each one-qubit unitary is a two-level unitary.

Comment: @glS I think you're mixing representations: The Reck etc. schemes are unitaries in $U(N)$, so they can be applied to $N=n$ qubits with $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$ two-level unitaries. These do not describe all unitaries acting on $n$ qubits, but they certainly are a subset of them. I.e., we do not need to use $\log N$ but simply $N$ here.

Comment: @QuantumMechanic I'm not really following. A unitary acting on $n$ qubits is in $U(2^n)$, not $U(n)$.

Comment: @glS emphatically, that is not always correct. You are mixing groups and their representations. If you think about spin, we always have the same three generators of SU(2): $J_x$, $J_y$, and $J_z$, yet they can act on any number $n$ qubits. But I agree that this does not nearly cover all of $U(2^n)$

Comment: @glS You are right about expressing the $2^n * 2^n$ size Hadamard gate as a tensor product of 'n' two level unitary matrices. But could you please tell me how to convert the tensor product of 'n' two level unitary matrices to the (matrix multiplication) product of 'n' two-level unitary matrices? I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: @QuantumMechanic By the n-qubit Hadamard matrix/ Quantum fourier transform matrix, I mean the $U(2^n)$ or the $2^n * 2^n$ unitary square matrix.

Comment: @QuantumMechanic I see we are referring to different things. I was simply talking about the general (group of) unitaries acting on $n$ qubits. You are talking about there possibly being submanifolds of unitaries acting on $n$-qubit states. Sure, but how do you apply Reck from this point of view? If you apply Reck's decomposition to your $U(N)$ subgroup, are you ensured that the two-level unitaries in that representation remain two-level unitaries when acting on the full $2^N$-dimensional space?

Comment: I was browsing through stackexchange and found the following post in Physics Stackexchange.                                                                  https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/532215/prove-that-there-exists-a-d-times-d-unitary-matrix-u-which-cannot-be-decomp                                                                                                           I believe the above post resolves the question that  it is NOT possible to decompose Hadamard/QFT matrices into polynomial number of two-level matrices. Please let me know if I am wrong.

Comment: @glS the answer is a matter of definition. It will certaintly not look like a two-level unitary in the computational basis, but it certainly will "[act] non-trivially only on two-or-fewer vector components" in some basis, which is broad enough to allow the usual CNOT gate to be a "two-level unitary." The crux is the size of the eigenspaces of the unitaries

Comment: @KarthikPC I understand. All I am saying that there exists a subset of unitaries that will indeed allow for such a decomposition and that one such relevant subset may be $U(n)$.

Comment: @gls I was wrong about two-level unitaries... mine will act *trivially* on two components as opposed to *non-trivially* - my mistake

Comment: @QuantumMechanic that is probably the best way to put it, I agree. I *think* in N&C "two-level matrix" is understood as a matrix which only acts nontrivially on a two-dimensional space *in the computational basis*. But it would be a fair extension to consider instead matrices acting nontrivially on *any* two-dimensional subspace.

Comment: @KarthikPC I'm not sure that answer addresses this question. That argument only shows that *some* $d\times d$ matrices need more than $d-1$ two-level ones. There are however certainly matrices which do not (as a trivial example, a two-level unitary can be decomposed using just a single two-level unitary...). You are right that what I said before for the Hadamard isn't accurate though: even single-qubit gates aren't two-level.The core issue is that talking about "two-level matrices" isn't really natural in the context of qubits, because those aren't easy gates to implement with qubits systems.

Comment: @gls agreed. Recently came across a relevant unitary (Eq 1 in https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.122.220501) that is a product of two-level matrices in the computational basis that seems like a nightmare to implement. They need recourse to Toffoli gates controlled by the other $n-1$ qubits, in their particular case

Comment: I found the following post in math stackexchange where the minimum number of Givens rotations to represent a orthogonal matrix is discussed. Givens rotation is nothing but the two-level matrices of quantum computing algorithms. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4285070/minimum-number-of-givens-rotations-required-to-describe-a-unitary-matrix The expression for the minimum number of two-level matrices is given as d - 2k where d is the number of rows/columns in the square  orthogonal matrix and k is the multiplicity of eigenvalue 1 for the orthogonal matrix. A proof would be great.